# What is the most efficient way to add and initialize a new std::map element?

Tags: c++, stdvector, stdmap

Say, if I have the following map, where each element contains an array:

```
struct STRUCT{
    int value;
    std::vector<MY_DATA> myArr;
};

std::map<UINT, STRUCT> myMap;
```

And then if I want to add a new element to that map and also initialize it at the same time:

```
//But, let's say we have a 'STRUCT' with a large number of items in the vector
std::vector<MY_DATA> arr;
arr.resize(0x10000);        //Arbitrary
int val = 123;

addToMap(&arr, val);
```

From what I understand I have the following ways to do it:

```
void addToMap1(UINT id, std::vector<MY_DATA>* pArr, int val)
{
    //Method 1
    STRUCT myStruct;
    myStruct.myArr = *pArr;
    myStruct.value = val;
    myMap[id] = myStruct;
}

void addToMap2(UINT id, std::vector<MY_DATA>* pArr, int val)
{
    //Method 2
    myMap[id] = STRUCT();
    STRUCT* pS = &myMap[id];
    pS->myArr = *pArr;
    pS->value = val;
}

void addToMap3(UINT id, std::vector<MY_DATA>* pArr, int val)
{
    //Method 3
    myMap[id] = STRUCT();
    std::map<UINT, STRUCT>::iterator itr = myMap.find(id);
    STRUCT* pS = &itr->second;
    pS->myArr = *pArr;
    pS->value = val;
}

void addToMap4(UINT id, std::vector<MY_DATA>* pArr, int val)
{
    //Method 4
    std::pair<std::map<UINT, STRUCT>::iterator, bool> prNew = 
        myMap.insert(std::pair<UINT, STRUCT>(id, STRUCT()));
    ASSERT(prNew.second);       //It must have not existed before!  
    STRUCT* pS = &prNew.first->second;
    pS->myArr = *pArr;
    pS->value = val;
}
```

But what is the most efficient way to do it?

Comment: Your functions have UB if you pass nullptr.

Comment: @eerorika: OK, let's assume no nulls.

Comment: It's a bad idea to assume. Better to make it impossible to pass null.

Comment: Using `insert` or `emplace` members will be more efficient because they don't create a new default initialized object first like using `[]` does.

Comment: @Shawn: Yeah, I thought too about the `insert`. But what's the `emplace` again?

Comment: @c00000fd, https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/emplace.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/emplace

Comment: I would bet time is spend in vector copy and not in default creation of `STRUCT`.

Comment: Does each element have a different vector?  Is the `map` an index table?

Comment: You may be able to make your program more efficient by using a pointer to the vector, in your structure.  The *ancient ones* have always preferred using a pointer to a large object in memory, rather than copying it.  Much faster to copy a pointer than to copy a large amount of data.

Comment: @Shawn: Nope. Neither `insert` nor `emplace` is a correct suggesstion. The original code clearly shows that the OP wants to **overwrite** data for existing keys. `insert` and `emplace` do not do that.

Answer (score 1):

If your intent implies *overwriting* the existing data for the key that is already present in the map, then just plain

```
void addToMap(UINT id, const std::vector<MY_DATA>* pArr, int val)
{
  STRUCT &pS = myMap[id];
  pS.value = val;
  pS.myArr = *pArr;
}
```

will do the trick quite efficiently. It is not clear why in your existing "methods" you insist on first saving a default-constructed `STRUCT()` into `myMap[id]`. This is completely unnecessary.

The other optimization opportunities would involve:

1. Moving data from the existing vector instead of copying it (if possible)
2. Not even constructing the source vector, and constructing the target vector directly in the map (if possible)
3. It the source vector is required to exist as an independent object (and is long-lived), then a pointer to that vector can be stored in the map instead of a full copy

But it is not clear from your description whether this is applicable in your case.

---

Note that you cannot use `emplace` for this purpose since `emplace` does not do what you want to do in this case: it does not overwrite data for existing keys. What we'd need in this case is a forwarding version of `insert_or_assign`, but alas it does not exist.

Comment: Yes, I see your point about updating an existing map item. But, no, the question is about adding a new item to the array. Probably using pointers to an array allocated on the heap (using the `new` operator) would be the fastest way to implement it. Unfortunately that also involves a heap of the management code to make sure that those pointers are copied, assigned, de-allocated, etc. As for your question about constructing an empty `STRUCT` in my methods 2, 3, 4, then how else would I add a new element into the map without constructing it? My goal of doing it is to prevent costly array copy.

Answer (score 0):

You might move ressource, something like:

```
void addToMap(UINT id, std::vector<MY_DATA>&& arr, int val)
{
    auto& s = myMap[id];
    s.myArr = std::move(arr);
    s.value = val;
}
```